# Populating textboxes from listview. Overload Error

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a program I wrote. It opens a new window named editItem.xaml. I set the title of the program and the variables of the program. Then I check to see if DialogResult = true and if it does then I refresh the listview with some other code. I can successfully grab the data from the listview to populate the textboxes with:

```
ei.txtEditEffectiveDate.Text = ((System.Data.DataRowView)(listView1.SelectedItem)).Row.ItemArray[1].ToString();
```

but the data is not formatted in anyway. So the date comes out as: 06/01/2014 12:00:00

I tried simply putting in the ToString("d"); to change the format but when I do I get an error:

```
No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments
```

And here is my code:

```
    private void editEntryInstance()
    {
        // Open editItem.xaml
        editItem ei = new editItem();

        // Assign the program a title
        ei.Title = "Edit Entry for Item: " + ((System.Data.DataRowView)(listView1.SelectedItem)).Row.ItemArray[0].ToString();

        // Get variables of entry
        ei.txtEditItem.Text = ((System.Data.DataRowView)(listView1.SelectedItem)).Row.ItemArray[0].ToString();
        ei.txtEditEffectiveDate.Text = ((System.Data.DataRowView)(listView1.SelectedItem)).Row.ItemArray[1].ToString();
        ei.txtEditTermDate.Text = ((System.Data.DataRowView)(listView1.SelectedItem)).Row.ItemArray[2].ToString();
        ei.txtEditMoq.Text = ((System.Data.DataRowView)(listView1.SelectedItem)).Row.ItemArray[3].ToString();
        ei.txtEditSetupCost.Text = ((System.Data.DataRowView)(listView1.SelectedItem)).Row.ItemArray[4].ToString();

        if (ei.ShowDialog().Value)
        {
            // Refresh after editing entry
            refreshInstance();
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: if this is WPF, I strongly recommend that you delete all that code and use proper DataBinding.

Comment: Can you please explain exactly what you mean?

Comment: WPF is not winforms. Read [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx). Also, All that `DataRow` stuff is highly undesirable. It forces you to all that casting stuff which is really ugly, bloats your code left and right and forces you into a bunch of stringly-typed stuff. It is strongly recommended that you create a proper strongly-typed data model and use proper DataBinding instead.

Comment: @HighCore Well this is my first C#/WPF program I have written so I used what I had available. But I will make sure to read over this and try to clean it up. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to apply `ToString("d")` on a string type value. This `ToString` overload is available with `DateTime` type object.

You need to convert your value to a `DateTime` type object and then apply `ToString("d")`.

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(((System.Data.DataRowView)(listView1.SelectedItem)).Row.ItemArray[1]);
ei.txtEditEffectiveDate.Text = dt.ToString("d");
```

You may need `DateTime.ParseExact` or `DateTime.TryParseExact` for parsing string values to `DateTime` if you the value contains date in custom format.

Comment: That worked perfectly. That makes sense. I was converting an object to a string and then trying to take the string and make it a date. Making it a DateTime first worked. Thank you.

Comment: I'm guessing this would also work for applying a currency:


    Decimal dec = Convert.ToDecimal(((System.Data.DataRowView)(listView1.SelectedItem)).Row.ItemArray[4]);
    ei.txtEditSetupCost.Text = dec.ToString("$#,###.##");

Comment: @ryantpayton, yes, but you can use `dec.ToString("C")` for currency

Comment: Thank you. dec.ToString("C") is much easier. Does the same thing but much cleaner.
I actually found them on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) as well.

Comment: What about `lblGoalSet.Text = intTargetScrap.ToString();`? intTargetScrap is an object (`object intTargetScrap;`). It's giving the same error: `No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments`

Comment: @ryantpayton, `ToString("C")` would work with numeric types, not a the object type. If your field is of `object` type, then first you have to convert to a numeric type like decimal and then use `ToString("C")`

Comment: Ahh okay. It worked. `Decimal dc = Convert.ToDecimal(intTargetScrap);
            lblGoalSet.Text = dc.ToString("c");` I was trying to follow the same procedure as the DateTime but I couldn't get it to work but I wasn't converting it to a Decimal first. Thanks again.